# Linking libraries depending on project configuration

Tags: c++, linker

Im developing a game engine. I work with **Visual Studio 2012** but I plan to migrate to 2015 Community soon.
I use dedicated physics engine (NVIDIA PhysX). I link its libraries in my header file, using `#pragma`:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libraryDEBUG.lib") // Example
```

PhysX API comes with different library versions for **debug** and **release** configurations. So, if I want to compile release version of my engine I must manualy change above code to:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libraryRELEASE.lib")
```

I want to automatize this process. This is what I figured out so far:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    #pragma comment(lib, "libraryRELEASE.lib")
#else
    #pragma comment(lib, "libraryDEBUG.lib") 
#endif
```

Is it propper way to do this? I know that `NDEBUG` just enables/disables assertions, but I cant see another way to do this.

Comment: Define "proper". IMHO, usual way is to setup linking in your build system, not in source files. i.e., for Visual Studio, it is linker options in project properties.

Comment: @Drop: Consistent with coding style \ Engineering standard.

Comment: No such standards really. And it has nothing to do with coding. It's more like build system set up. BTW, `#pragma comment(lib,...)` will not work on most compilers. Also, let's say on Linux, there is traditionally no such thing as "debug libraries" (at least not that you could find in repositories).

Comment: On the other hand, if `#pragma comment(lib,...)` works for you, then use it. For example, boost C++ libraries use this pragma in Windows builds, so libraries are being linked automagically, you just need to `#include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do it in Visual Studio is to change the project configuration settings under `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`.

Add something like `Library$(ConfigurationName).lib` to both debug and release configurations.

If you want a portable solution (e.g. you don't have to share your project files), consider using CMake to generate solutions and configurations for you.

As for the `NDEBUG` option - it is valid as long as windows is your only target platform.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.